# Using namespace on include file

Tags: php, namespaces

I have a class:

```
namespace Navi\View;

use Navi\Navi;

class View extends Base{
    public function render(){
        $test = 'This is a local variable!';
        $obj = new Navi; //Working, ofcourse!
        include 'file.php';
    }
}
```

And in "file.php";

```
<?php
echo $test;
var_dump(new Navi); //Class Navi not found
```

Why the local $test variable pass to file.php, but Navi class isn't?

Ofcourse, if I use "use Navi\Navi" in "file.php" then code working. I don't understand why!

Any way to using Navi class that not using "use Navi\Navi"?

Please help me!

Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

Importing rules are per file basis, meaning included files will NOT inherit the parent file's importing rules.

I've go to change your code in file.php this way:

```
var_dump(new \Navi\Navi)
```